# How to enforce type safety in TypeScript when using Parameters with generic function types?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I'm trying to achieve type safety in TypeScript when using the `Parameters` utility type. However, I'm facing an issue where the `Parameters` type does not take into account a generic function type `TFunc` when inferring the argument type.

Here's an example of the functions involved:

```js
const funcExecutor = <TFunc extends (...args: any[]) => void>(data: {
  func: TFunc;
  mapParams: () => Parameters<TFunc>[0];
}) => data.func(data.mapParams());

const funcExecutorHandler = <TAction extends (arg: any) => any>(
  action: TAction,
  data: Parameters<TAction>[0],
) => {};
```

The `funcExecutor` function is type-safe and can be called as follows:

```js
funcExecutor({
  func: (param: { foo: boolean }) => param,
  mapParams() {
    return {
      foo: true, // TYPE SAFE
    };
  },
});
```

The issue arises when using the `funcExecutorHandler` function, which is a generic function that can take any function and expects parameters based on the provided function's parameter types. In this example, the intention is to enforce type safety for the `mapParams` function. However, it fails to do so.

```js
funcExecutorHandler(funcExecutor, {
  func: (param: { foo: boolean }) => param,
  mapParams() {
    return {
      foo: 'bad', // NOT TYPE SAFE
    };
  },
});
```

The issue lies in the fact that the `Parameters<TAction>[0]` type does not take the generic function type `TFunc` into account, resulting in the inability to enforce type safety for the `mapParams` function.

Is there a way to make the `Parameters` type inference dependent on the generic function type `TFunc` in this scenario? Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Parameters<T>` is a conditional type, and thus you're dealing with *generic* conditional types, which the compiler can't reason about properly.  Even `funcExectutor` is not "type safe" since it lets you call `funcExecutor({ func: (x: string, y: number) => console.log(y.toFixed()), mapParams: () => "" });` without realizing that it's a problem.  I'd recommend avoiding `Parameters<T>` entirely unless you have some use case not shown here.  (continued)

Comment: (continued) Even if you fix that, TS can't do higher order generic type unification easily, so you'll probably need an instantiation expression, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBQQgw) for it to work.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I apologize for the late response. Originally I was hoping not to explicitly specify the type and just use the function, but as you mentioned it is not supported by typescript. Please do write up an answer i will set it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is essentially unable to perform the sort of higher-order type manipulation you're looking for.  The inference algorithm can't perform arbitrary [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type instantiation, which is what you'd need to get this to work.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#52010](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52010) and [microsoft/TypeScript#49690](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49690) for more information.

So [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is not going to be able to synthesize a type that's generic the way you need it to be.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#43731](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43731) for more information.

What you'll end up seeing is that the "inner" generic type parameters will be replaced with their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) which is often `unknown`.

---

Furthermore, `Parameters<T>` is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and the type checker can't really perform accurate analysis on such types when `T` is generic, such as inside the body of `funcExecutor()`.  It will sometimes complain about safe things because it leaves the type as opaque and can't figure out what might be assignable to it.  Other times it will try to make progress by evaluating the type prematurely and allowing unsafe things.  For example, your `funcExecutor` function implementation is unsafe but the compiler misses it:

```
funcExecutor({
    func: (x: string, y: number) => console.log(y.toFixed()),
    mapParams: () => ""
}); //  y is undefined
```

That call satisfies the call signature for `funcExecutor()`, with `TFunc` being of type `(x: string, y: number) => void`, but you get a runtime error because only the first argument is passed.  The body of `funcExecutor()` really should have a compiler error, but the compiler missed the problem because it made a bad assumption about what `Parameters<TFunc>` looks like.

---

My suggestion here is to refactor away from conditional types (your functions really only need to be generic in the single argument type, not the whole function type), and to use an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) to specify the type argument that the compiler is unable to infer.  Like this:

```
const funcExecutor = <A,>(data: {
    func: (arg: A) => void;
    mapParams: () => A;
}) => data.func(data.mapParams());

const funcExecutorHandler = <A,>(
    action: (arg: A) => void,
    data: A,
) => { };

funcExecutor({
    func: (param: { foo: boolean }) => param,
    mapParams() {
        return {
            foo: true, // TYPE SAFE
        };
    },
});

funcExecutor({
    func: (x: string, y: number) => console.log(y.toFixed()), // error!
    mapParams: () => ""
}) 

funcExecutorHandler(funcExecutor<{ foo: boolean }>, {
    // -----------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    func: (param: { foo: boolean }) => param,
    mapParams() { // error!
        return {
            foo: 'bad',
        };
    },
});
```

Now you get errors where you'd expect them: the unsafe call to `funcExecutor()` is now a compiler error because it requires more params than the call signature allows; and the `funcExecutorHandler()` call fails because it knows that `{foo: "bad"}` is not a `{foo: boolean}`.

This is a bit more type specifying than you'd like, but it's not *that* bad, especially because it frees you up from having to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the `func` callback parameter type, so it's about equal in terms of complexity:

```
funcExecutorHandler(funcExecutor<{ foo: boolean }>, {
    func: (param) => param, // known to be {foo: boolean}
    mapParams: () => ({ foo: true })
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAeQE4EsDmKDewKxKiA9iDAC4oBmAriIgKIAeUi9VZGKAvCgA8AFQBijRCiisqUEABMYKABQA6dWAw4YALhRgQATwDaAXQCU-AHwoAbmSzyry+WCpg9hEt7oS9YiQBuIh9iCDA4AAVNSF0VSz4baIxIKFkMGBFxJitjAAZTYO8AXwSbV3dVBiYXNzBVcKiYiBhlc3NgkOIqDEMCLp9qlnZObgxlL1DBvxVWPWpsEBwAGhRDPRB6CAAjKAwy0goYMgAbKFUTshxlQ1VuUSx2eTbzZYGplEbk2L026xQAEQA94kUooAD04JQGEYVCw0CkGAwPFWfSwSkY8igtCwICg8gAhANiqQ3IgABYqKCWSahciUU7nS7XanE4DAYrAenUXxMNgcLg8fhCACCy2cFQ8-W8Q1+mhwehFB3sjiKJC+zTif0SKBFwTBOslVQktUqGpSLRenW5NCG-NGPAAEgZ5GdeAJBGLnAMkHCKHKtIrlQ55G9vJLFW8DvgUMVOnaRoLxrTeYhfggLZ46GQyHptjmzgZYwcM5Aw+qIt9LTSQcQMGl6BgQNKPiRaDm9D16FBVpCUMIAJqRZgoADKItEzFrsbVxGKb1KnWAPT6KYTArGE2nstm8x6uJWaw2W12+3+3MZFyuNzuZAeTxevahe2RGCJH3NP3i-yBxMsfZhEA4QRF8UTWFB0RQTFsVxfEiRJRAyUpZRqRbYgLzOK8WXMDl2XXB0MGdBQ3WUfCk0EGN21zFB80ZItiisVYUz7ABaNj2I4ziuLYmwAD1+IEwShIEgYd2UUsICzKi8wLKB6JLZpyzCStNT+GM+1At9p3rKhG2bFMPmklAAHJtjAeRjKUnw42JBcOjwiR7STIjXT2UjHMTMYKOzajaMLZsGKY0SZnE5oFItKzPxaX4DgmHzOxhVBSg5DogA)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation, thank you!